# How to prove that only 4n x 4m rectangles can be tiled with T tetrominoes?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I have a problem tiling a rectangle with T tetrominoes. I can prove that 4n x 4m rectangles can be tiled.How can I prove that only these rectangles can be tiled with T tetrominoes?

Comment: If you can tile a 4 x 4 region, you can tile a 4n x 4m region. The more interesting part of the problem is proving that if it isn't 4n x 4m, it can't be tiled with Ts/

Comment: See for example https://mathoverflow.net/questions/28883/what-can-be-tiled-by-t-tetrominoes . This is not an easy problem.

Comment: Yes its the main problem @DonThousand

Comment: I read paper, it defines a chain  graph and height function, but I didn't see the clear proof of this claim @MichaelLugo

Comment: @Liana Take some time to read through papers. You can't expect to digest them instantaneously.

Comment: thanks @DonThousand